# Problem by passing a value from ng-repeat in a parameter from a function call

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the problem, that i can´t pass the value (x) from the ng-repeat in a parameter for a function (laenge2()). Only error i get is: x is not defined.

```
<div class="input-group mb-3" ng-repeat="x in laenge">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id={{x}} onchange="laenge2({{x}})" style="background-color: white">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">{{x}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the `ng-model` directive and the `ng-change` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ng-model` directive and the `ng-change` directive.

```
$scope.laenge2 = new Array($scope.laenge.length);
```

```
<div class="input-group mb-3" ng-repeat="x in laenge">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id={{x}}
           ng-model="laenge2[$index]" ng-change="someFn(x)"
           style="background-color: white">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">{{x}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```